# Getting a column from an array in jinja2 python

Tags: python, jinja2

I have an array

```
{% set myarray = [['apple', true, false],
['banana', false, true]] %}
```

I want to get

```
['apple', 'banana']
```

why is something easy so hard with jinja?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`do`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/extensions/) extension for jinja2

> The “do” aka expression-statement extension adds a simple do tag to the template engine that works like a variable expression but ignores the return value.

## Python

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.jinja_env.add_extension('jinja2.ext.do')
```

## HTML

```
{% set myarray = [['apple', true, false],['banana', false, true]] %}
{% set second_array = [] %}

{% for a in myarray %}
    {% do second_array.append(a[0]) %}
{% endfor %}

{{ second_array }}
```

Another way you can do this, without using the `do` extension,  is to generate a custom `filter` and use standard list comprehension

## Python

```
def get_nth(lst, i):
    return [l[i] for l in lst]
app.jinja_env.filters['get_nth'] = get_nth
```

## HTML

```
{{ myarray|get_nth(0) }}
```

Comment: If i have to do all of that just to get a column I will cry

Comment: @Toskan if you want to just output the data, you can just do 'my_array[0]' in a loop, but this way allows you to store the values into another array

Comment: I know how to output a value from an array. But it's saddening that jinja is so bad. I will cry.

Comment: I will agree that jinja is quite a pain in this aspect

Comment: there is literally 0 occurrences of the word `array` on http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/

Comment: @Toskan I added another way to achieve this, without using jinja extensions. Still not native to jinja2, but it is reusable